# How do I work out an unknown probability? (Sorry if I'm not specific enough details in main body)

Tags: probability, quadratics

There are two blue beads and x red beads in a box. The probability that two random beads taken at random from the box are both red is 15/22, how do I work out x?

Comment: How would you work out the number $15/22$ if you had $x$? Let's say, $x=10$. Now, what is the probability that two random beads are both red?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

There are $x+2$ beads total, hence the probability of selecting a red bead first is $\frac{x}{x+2}$

What will the probability of selecting another red bead after this be?

Comment: Selecting another red bead would be x /x+1 so the equation would be x/x+2 times x-1/x+1 = 15/22, how would I work out x then? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious but my teacher hasn't gone over any of this.

Comment: You're close, you took out the bead from the total amount of beads, but not the amount of red beads. If you take out one red bead there will be $x-1$ red beads in the box.

Comment: Oh right afterwards it's just a quadratics question, that really help thanks for the help bro!

Comment: Yeah its just a quadratic after that. When you collect like terms I recommend the $ac$ method, as it factors nicely.

Answer (score -1):

The probability of picking two red balls (by uniform picking) is:

$$p = \frac {x}{x+2} \times \frac {x-1}{x+1} = \frac {x^2 - x}{(x+2)(x+1)}.$$

You want this probability to equal $\frac {15}{22}$. Just make these two quantities equal and you find the following equation:

$$\begin{aligned}
15(x^2 + 3x + 2) &= 22(x^2-x) \\
7x^2 - 67x - 30 &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

Which gives you the (positive) solution $x = 10$.

Comment: So basically my hint but with the answer given away. Thanks. Moreover this answer is problematic as you are giving results *without* explanation. This leads to such an answer being totally useless when method replication is attempted on a similar question.